# Wordpress - Page Aliasing

Tags: wordpress

I don't know why I am having difficulties finding an answer for this, but I was. I am hoping it's quick and painless.

This is my first attempt at a WordPress site. I created a number of pages which reside in a standard navigation. Currently the nav links look like such:

?page_id=2

I want link to be friendly such as:

/restaurant/

I went into the permalinks and tried messing around with the options and I got the URLs to change but on click I get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two things i could think of

- Wordpress can't write the .htaccess file (a warning should be displayed on the permalink page). In that case update it by hand with code shown on the site.
- mod_rewrite is disabled on your server http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: The rewrite was not enabled in Apache. Thanks.